# How To Test Sending Thousands Of Emails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I'm developing an application that will send thousands of emails per day based on a CSV file using Amazon SES.

My client would like to send around 50,000 in one hit.

The app is almost done however i would like to test it with thousands of emails. What a shame would it be that on my first try with live data it doesn't work.

Right now i have only tested it using about 10 emails in my CSV file.

Does anyone know of a way to test sending around 10,000 emails? Obviously i can't use real data.

Comment: Did you try with mailbox simulator by Amazon SES?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you can use real data. To test 10,000 emails for example, you can do the following (assuming you've already [increased your SES sending limits](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/increase-sending-limits.html)):

1. Generate 10,000 email recipients in your CSV file for a target domain **that you already manage**. Those 10,000 email addresses should be random and non-existent (e.g., 1eed1417-cc2c-4f7c-8ddb-7e0dfbcacb31@mydomain.com).
2. Configure a catch-all email address for mydomain.com (e.g., catch-all@mydomain.com) to receive emails sent to any non-existent address.
3. Add SES SMTP servers to mydomain.com's trusted senders/addresses and make sure your mailserver's throttling rules allow this sending volume.
4. Test during off-peak hours and check the inbox of your catch-all mailbox.

Answer (score 1):

What i ended up doing is using https://mailtrap.io/

I made 25 emails. Then sent 600 emails to each of the 25 emails. That equals 15,000.

I didnt use action mailer to send the emails. I used the Amazon SES send email method

```
  def send_email!
    client.send_email(email_attributes)
  end

  private

  def client
    Aws::SES::Client.new(region: Rails.application.secrets.ses_region,
                         access_key_id: Rails.application.secrets.aws_access_key_id,
                         secret_access_key: Rails.application.secrets.aws_secret_access_key)
  end
```

Used Kabana for tracking the emails. If they bounced, delivered and so on.

SES won't track email opens so we have a small Node-JS app that will track opens and clickable links.

The app sends around 15000 emails in 20minutes.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are not doing a full end-to-end test (which includes checking to ensure the email was received) but rather are just performing a functional test of your application logic.

If that is the case,

1. Point your application at a test email server and [disable outbound email for all queues](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124880(v=exchg.65).aspx).  You could also do this on a production server, at say 3:00 am, I guess, but be careful!
2. Run the application
3. Check the email server's outbox and count the number of items that have queued up.
4. If the count matches, your test has passed.
5. Don't forget to purge the queue before turning it back on!